# Node js wait for request.get callback happens and then go to next line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make one request to URL and then I am fetching image data from that. Now what I need to do is:

1. Get Image data from request
2. Assign this data to one variable
3. Now print this/ push this data

What I am doing ?

```
var data;
request.get(URL, function (error, response, body) { //1
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data = "data:" 
            + response.headers["content-type"]
            + ";base64,"
            + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
        }
    });
console.log(data) //2
```

Problem ?

Now I need request to happen at first and then move to console.log so that my data will be not undefined and then later I can push it in my dictionary. But right now it makes one request from 1 and then it moves to 2 which is console.log and then it gives error. So what I can do ?

Note: I don't want to add console.log inside that function because I can't put all my code below request inside that function.

Comment: Just add a console.log(response) inside your if statement.you can see the response of image data

Comment: Every subsequent tasks, and I mean _every_ single one of them, must be called within the callback. The problem is that JS is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Async/Await are the keywords which will tell your code to wait for the result from a function to continue. That's called [Asynchronous code](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

```
function getData() {
   return request.get(URL, function (error, response, body) { //1
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = "data:"
            + response.headers["content-type"]
            + ";base64,"
            + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
            return data
        }
    });
}
```

And then in the function, you need your data for treatment

```
async function main() {
   var myData = await getData();


  ... Your treatment of data
}
```

You can have more information about Synchronous/Asynchronous code in javascript [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the URL which you mentioned at last ... It was really informative and really helped me a lot. I can't say that it solved my problem completely but yes it changed my thinking process a lot and no doubt it helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: This code will not work because returning something from a callback is not the same as resolving a promise, which the `main()` function expects. You need to return a `Promise` from the `getData()` function in order to actually use async/await.